# ASP.Net Core OtlpExporter for NewRelic not working

Tags: asp.net-core, newrelic, otlp-grpc

I'm trying to export metrics, traces and logs to NewRelic by using OtlpExporter, however I'm not having any success.
I setup my Program.cs as follows on a simple .Net 7 API and the sympton is that nothing shows on NewRelic.
My license key is correct. If I enable console logging I don't see any kind of error or warning. I don't have any environment variable configured apart from what we see here on the code. Am I missing anything that would make this work?

```
 using OpenTelemetry;
using OpenTelemetry.Logs;
using OpenTelemetry.Metrics;
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var endpoint = new Uri("https://otlp.eu01.nr-data.net");
var exportProcessorType = ExportProcessorType.Batch;
var protocol = OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OtlpExportProtocol.Grpc;
var headers = $"api-key=aaaaaaa";


builder.Logging.AddOpenTelemetry(logging =>
{
    logging.IncludeScopes = true;

    var resourceBuilder = ResourceBuilder
        .CreateDefault()
        .AddService("WeatherForecast");

    logging.SetResourceBuilder(resourceBuilder)
    //.AddConsoleExporter()
    .AddOtlpExporter(configure =>
        {
            configure.Endpoint = endpoint;
            configure.ExportProcessorType = exportProcessorType;
            configure.Protocol = protocol;
            configure.Headers = headers;
        });
});

//  Exporter
//  URL: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/more-integrations/open-source-telemetry-integrations/opentelemetry/get-started/opentelemetry-set-up-your-app/#review-settings
//  Link: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/tree/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OpenTelemetryProtocol

builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .WithMetrics(builder => builder
            .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
            //.AddConsoleExporter()
            .AddOtlpExporter(configure =>
            {
                configure.Endpoint = endpoint;
                configure.ExportProcessorType = exportProcessorType;
                configure.Protocol = protocol;
                configure.Headers = headers;
            }))
        .WithTracing(builder => builder
            .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
            //.AddConsoleExporter()
            .AddOtlpExporter(configure =>
            {
                configure.Endpoint = endpoint;
                configure.ExportProcessorType = exportProcessorType;
                configure.Protocol = protocol;
                configure.Headers = headers;
            }));



var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```